# Dual-boot on new computer with SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

This is a basic question.  I have found a lot of material on SSD's and dual-booting, but they are about set-ups that are much more nuanced than what I'm interested in.  My question is simply this: if I buy a new computer that has an SSD, does it introduce any problems for dual-booting compared to a traditional hard-drive?

I've seen stuff on HDD+SSD, which I assume relates to using one drive to hold boot files and the OS, and the other to hold data.  That sounds too complicated and I don't want to do that.

I want to run Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine.  I read that SSD's provide massive performance gains, so I'd like to purchase a laptop with an SSD.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not have any problems with it being an SSD. I would suggest create recovery media, then reinstall using a Windows 10 setup usb or disc. During setup, create your partition sizes so when you install ubuntu alongside windows it does not screw up your windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

It will have no difference at all, other than a performance gain.

Comment: The question was if it will have problems.

Comment: @Tim Only if it had problems on your HDD :P